# How to apply tail command in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am defining my two colum data file as below in gnuplot file, `plot.gnu`.

```
FILE2='case.out'
```

I want to store the last value of second colum of `case.out` as `Max`. I tried as

```
Max =`(tail -n 2 FILE2 | awk '{print $2}')`
```

But it gives gives me error

```
Max =
      ^
"plot.gnu", line 37: constant expression required
```

But if I define exact name of file, `case.out`, instead writing `FILE2` in Max command then it works well.

My case.out is something line

```
3.2853  243.4008
3.2936  243.6239
3.3019  243.8089
3.3103  243.9544
3.3186  244.0590
3.3269  244.1221
3.3353  244.1432
```

and I want the the `Max` command should store `244.1432` value.
i.e

```
print Max
```

should give  `244.1432`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the manual and or in the gnuplot console type `help stats`. No need for awk here.

**Code:**

```
stats "case.out" u 2 nooutput

print STATS_max
```

**Result:**

```
244.1432
```

**Addition:**

Please check the manual about how `stats` works.

**Code:**

```
stats "case.out" u 1:2 nooutput

print STATS_min_x, STATS_max_x
print STATS_min_y, STATS_max_y
```

**Result:**

```
3.2853 3.3353

243.4008 244.1432
```

Or you can even "rename" the stats results.

**Code:**

```
stats "case1.out" u 1:2 nooutput name "First"
print First_min_x, First_max_x
print First_min_y, First_max_y

stats "case2.out" u 1:2 nooutput name "Second"
print Second_min_x, Second_max_x
print Second_min_y, Second_max_y
```

Comment: But I am using stats for other file in the same plot.gnu file that will decide the X-axis maximum and using this Max variable, I want to define Y-axis maximum. Using stats in a single gnuplot script  is overlapping the previous one.

Comment: stats FILE2 u 1:2 nooutput
print STATS_min_x
print STATS_min_y
print STATS_max_x
print STATS_max_y
After your advise, I tried above and it worked for me. Thank you Sir.